# MVC webgrid's paging and sorting are not working when placed inside Bootstrap modal popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside the Bootstrap modal popup MVC webgrid's paging and sorting are not working. Showing as jQuery undefined. This modal popup is being kept in a partial view. All the jQuery related js are been kept in the main view and been referred to make them work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue raised because in more than one grid I have used same update container ID and same ajax call back function.